# Python Matplot Y Axis Negative to Positive Label Range

Tags: matplotlib, label, deviation

I'm trying to create y axis labels in a sequence of -20 to + 20 with 5 integer increments. I've tried this below with my plot axis = ax2:

```
ax2.set_yticks(list(range(-20, 25, 5)))
ax2.set_yticklabels([abs(y) for y in list(range(-20, 25, 5))])
```

and I get a y axis ranging from 20 to 20 that looks like this figure below:

[image: figure from my program that needs new axis labels (negative numbers)]

I need the y axis labels to list on the figure as: -20, -15, -10, -5, 0, 5, 10, 15, 20 and I've yet to find a solution online. Thank you for any help here!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `abs` which always returns a positive number. Therefore, you don't see negative ticklabels. Moreover, you don't need list comprehension and neither do you need to convert `range` to `list`. You can also just use a variable rather than calling `range()` twice.

Just remove the `abs` and pass the `range` directly. In fact, for your current example, you don't even need to set y-ticklabels. Just setting the ticks would be sufficient.

For example:

```
fig, ax2 = plt.subplots()

ytics = range(-20, 25, 5)
ax2.set_yticks(ytics)
ax2.set_yticklabels(ytics); # Remove abs() (Also redundant line in your case)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Does this work for you:

```
ax.set_yticks(np.linspace(-20, 20, 10))
```

Minimal example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(-20, 25, 5))
plt.show()
```

Plots:
[image]

Comment: @Sheldore sure it does! I just wanted to offer another possibility :)